# Emacs elisp with TCP/IP: Process xxx deleted message

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to run my own elisp code that worked happily 20 years ago (at that time I was using Linux). I'm running my .el (or .elc) file on Mac OSX emacs (version 22.1) on Terminal now.

The elisp program is essentially using the TCP/IP with the server that is written in perl.

I see the elisp code runnning fine but after the TCP/IP communication happens, the terminal inserts "Process net deleted" text on the emacs terminal screen.

I'm pretty sure the name "net" is coming from those elisp code:

```
(setq pipe (open-network-stream "net" network_buffer Host 10000))
(process-send-string pipe send)
(accept-process-output pipe)
(delete-process pipe)
```

The problem is I don't know why the emacs shows "Process net deleted" everytime the codes above are executed.

Can any of elisp gurus shed any insight why this message shows up?

I'm aware of the documentation of "network-stream.el" http://repo.or.cz/w/emacs.git/blob/HEAD:/lisp/net/network-stream.el but I have no clue so far.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the default behavior of Emacs when a "process" (network or otherwise) terminates.  You can override it with something like

```
(set-process-sentinel pipe #'ignore)
```